# Is there another less crowded route up to Schloss Neuschwanstein?

Tags: hiking, germany

We visited [Neuschwanstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuschwanstein_Castle) lately and since we were with kids, picked the common tourist path up to the castle. The hike is extremely stressful (for me at least) because you wander on a tarred way with thousands of other people while getting constantly taken over by carriages or even cars.

Are there any other more peaceful routes to the castle? I know that the official way is the only one leading to the "front-door". So, neglect this fact. It's enough if the path ends near the castle and on the same height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any other more peaceful routes to the castle?

Yes, there is another trail called Jugendstrasse. It leads towards the Alpsee lake, around to Mary's bridge and eventually back to Neuschwanstein.

There are other smaller trails the locals and staff use.

It has been 4 years since we were there, we walked all of the red and blue trails on this map:

[image: Cinderella routes]

The red route is perpetually stressful.